# Multilevel inheritance problem

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Please help me on this puzzle

i have class D  inherited fronm class B and class C, these class C and Class D again  inherited from class A. In class D i have to access function in class A. is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can and you probably want to  use virtual inheritance.  If you don't use virtual inheritance then you'll need to use `B::f()` or `C::f()` to specify which one you want to use.  If you use virtual inheritance you can use just `f()`.

[See my answer here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-problem/2659142#2659142)