# Virtual Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, virtual

To solve the diamond problem we go for virtual inheritance.

```
class A {}
class B : virtual Public A {}
class C : virtual Public A {}
class D : public B, Public C {}
```

Why is it not defined like:

```
class A {}
class B : public A {}
class C : public A {}
class D : virtual public B, virtual public C {}
```

What is the technical reason behind having the existing solution to solve diamond problem in C++ and not the second one. 
Is it not awkward to change the inheritance of base classes to solve some issue in derived class.

It would be great, If somebody can provide the technical intricacies.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-problem):-

You want: (Achievable with virtual inheritance)

```
   D
  / \
 B   C
  \ /
   A
```

And not: (What happens without virtual inheritance)

```
    D
   / \
  B   C
  |   |
  A   A
```

Comment: I know that. My question is more on syntax. Why can't we have second syntax? What is the reason behind?

Comment: The reason is well explained here :- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem#The_diamond_problem

Comment: C++ by default follows each inheritance path separately, so D object would actually contain two separate A objects, and uses of A's members have to be properly qualified.

Comment: If the inheritance from A to B and inheritance from A to C are both marked "virtual" (for example, "class B : virtual public A"), C++ takes special care to only create one A object, and uses of A's members work correctly. If virtual inheritance and nonvirtual inheritance are mixed, there is a single virtual A and a nonvirtual A for each nonvirtual inheritance path to A.C++ requires stating explicitly which parent class the feature to be used is invoked from.