# Difference between virtual and simple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

What is the difference between

```
class A {};
class Z: public A {};
```

and

```
class A {};
class Z: virtual public A {};
```

Comment: You may take a look at the "diamond problem". See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-problem).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that there is no additional inheritance hierarchy, there is no difference in this case. The only way to see a difference is inheriting the same class through multiple ways - for example, as follows:

```
class ZA : public Z, public A {};
```

vs.

```
class ZA : virtual public Z, virtual public A {};
```

In the first case, `ZA` would have two regions with separate `A`s - one inherited directly, and one inherited through `Z`. In the second case, there would be only one `A`, inherited through both paths, and shared.

Here is an illustration of this:

[image: Virtual vs. Regular inheritance]

Comment: Ok.. so... What's the difference??

Comment: `Assuming that there is no additional inheritance hierarchy, there is no difference in this case.` This is not true. In the first case, `sizeof(Z)` is typically one. But in the second case, `sizeof(Z)` is typically `sizeof(void*)` because `Z` will contain a vtable pointer even if `A` and `Z` do not contain virtual member functions.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the behaviour when you inherit from multiple classes which share a common base class:

```
class A {};
class Y : public A {};
class Z : public A {};
class YZ: public Y, public Z {};
```

In this case, with non-virtual inheritance, a `YZ` object would contain `Y` and `Z` subobjects, each with their own `A` subobject.

This is usually not what you want, as it doesn't follow the "is-a" relationship that inheritance usually models: there are two different ways in which a `YZ` can be viewed as an `A`.

```
void f(A&);
YZ yz;
f(yz);    // ERROR: which A?
```

But with virtual inheritance of `A`, there will be only one `A` subobject, shared by the `Y` and `Z`; the example above will now be unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two derived classes `B` and `C` that have a common base class `A`. And you have another class `D` that inherits both of them. You would use `public virtual A` to ensure that both `B` and `C` use the same subobject `A`.

Info taken from here: [Virtual Base Classes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr135.htm)