# How virtual keyword resolves ambiguity in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++

I know compiler gives error for ambiguity if we don't mention virtual keyword while deriving child class in diamond problem. So how virtual keyword removes this ambiguity?

Comment: Apparent duplicate: [How does virtual inheritance solve the “diamond” (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2659116/1149924)

Answer (score 0):

From
[isocpp faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-where)

```
class Base {
public:
  // ...
protected:
  int data_;
};
class Der1 : public virtual Base {
                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ // This is the key
public:
  // ...
};
class Der2 : public virtual Base {
                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ // This is the key
public:
  // ...
};
class Join : public Der1, public Der2 {
public:
  void method()
  {
     data_ = 1;  // Good: this is now unambiguous
  }
};
int main()
{
  Join* j = new Join();
  Base* b = j;   // Good: this is now unambiguous
}
```

if you didn't specify the inheritance as virtual, the compiler would try to add two `Base` classes in the `Derived` object, and it wouldn't know which `data_` to fill in. You would effectively have two objects that are the same in your derived class. 
Declaring the inheritance as `virtual` tells the compiler that you want only one instance of the base class in the derived class.

Comment: Thanks dau_sama. In this case size of Join class is 12 which include 2 virtual pointer of Der1, Der2 and 4bytes of data_(I think). Is it correct? Also which path is used by the compiler  to maintain single copy of Base object?

Comment: I think that's correct in gcc/x86, but it is implementation defined. Probably on other architectures it might be implemented in a different way. 
In this simple case the compiler simply knows that it only has to reserve one instance the base object in the memory layout.