# Accessing Base class from sub-sub-class or grandchild

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, base-class

I just want to get something straight because while I was learning about inheritance I noticed that I can inherit from an already derived class, and from the most derived class access the Base class's member directly. I think the following shows what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    int member = 0;     // All members null
};

struct D1 : Base {};
struct D2 : Base {};
struct D3 : Base {};
struct D4 : Base {};

struct MostDerived : D1, D2, D3, D4 {};  // I know MostDerived now has 4 copies of Base


int main()
{
    MostDerived mostderived{};
    mostderived.D2::member = 2;                     // D2::Base::member = 2
    mostderived.D3::member = 3;                     // D3::Base::member = 3
    mostderived.D4::member = 4;                     // D4::Base::member = 4

    std::cout << mostderived.D1::member << '\n';        // Haven't touched D1, is still zero
    std::cout << mostderived.D1::Base::member << '\n';  // Equals 0, equivalent to above line
    std::cout << mostderived.Base::member << '\n';      // Read Base scope directly from most derived, equals zero

    mostderived.Base::member++;                         // Assign to member in Base scope directly from mostderived
                                                        // it now equals 1

    std::cout << mostderived.D1::member << '\n';        // But also does D1::member equal 1

    return 0;
}
```

So by doing `mostderived.Base::member++` I changed the value of `mostderived.D1::member`. I'm just wondering if accessing `Base` like that makes any sense and why it particularly changed `D1`'s copy of member. The way I'm picturing the layout is that `MostDerived` contains `D1`, `D2`, `D3`, `D4`, and each of those contain a `Base`, so it looks like the following.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I often hear to favour composition over inheritance, and my debugger actually shows derived classes as "containing" the base classes, so I suppose inheritance isn't so different from just popping the base class into the derived class definition, except that it comes with other features of course.

Comment: The code doesn't build for me with `main.cpp:24:40: error: 'Base' is an ambiguous base of 'MostDerived'
     std::cout << mostderived.D1::Base::member << '\n';`

Comment: @kim366 I see, that's interesting. I've only tried on my Visual Studio, so maybe it should be an ambiguous thing. Though I would have thought the ambiguous part would have been the mostderived.Base::member part

Comment: Have a look at this explanation of regular vs virtual inheritance, it may clear things up a bit :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659142/7034621

Comment: @Zebrafish paste your code into here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ to see all errors in g++

Comment: I see, the error that makes sense to me is error: 'Base' is an ambiguous base of 'MostDerived', that definitely seems the case. I can't see any reason why modifying mostderived.Base::member would modify mostderived.D1::member, it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So by doing mostderived.Base::member++ I changed the value of
>   mostderived.D1::member.

If 'MostDerived' inherits from D1-4, then

```
mostderived.Base::member++;
                  ^
```

Is ambiguous.

Becouse 'MostDerived' has this hierarchy

```
int Base::member
int Base::member
int Base::member
int Base::member
```

and `Base` can be replaced with any of D1-4.

---

If you would use virtual inheritance

```
struct D1 : virtual Base {};
struct D2 : virtual Base {};
struct D3 : virtual Base {};
struct D4 : virtual Base {};
```

It would cause that 'MostDerived' would contain just **one** base class, so it wouldnt be ambiguous anymore to do

```
mostderived.Base::member++;
```

And it would be possible to access this `member` through all D1-4

```
mostderived.D1::member = 1;
mostderived.D4::member = 4;
```

of course since all D's share same variable, it would have same value for all, example:

```
MostDerived mostderived{};
mostderived.Base::member = 1;
std::cout << mostderived.D1::member << mostderived.D2::member << mostderived.D3::member << mostderived.D4::member;
```

Will print `1111`.

Comment: As kim366 pointed out it doesn't compile on the online compiler linked. It definitely makes sense that it's ambiguous. I was running on Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have any other questions about this? :-)

Comment: No, I understand now that it's an ambiguous expression and probably a bug in my compiler. Thanks.

Comment: I will soon edit my answer with `virtual` inheritance on this example you can take a look after. You are welcome.