# "X is an ambiguous base of Y": Multiple inheritance nightmare

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Below is the class hierarchy I have.

All `Ixxxx` classes are *interfaces* (abstract classes with no member data).

All arrows represent inheritance.

Colors are only here to provide better visualisation.

[image: class hierarchy]

Somewhere in the code using these classes, I have to pass a `Track*` where an `IConnectableTrack*` is expected, and I get the following compilation error:

```
error: ‘IConnectableTrack’ is an ambiguous base of ‘Track’
```

I know this is a matter of multiple inheritance, but I tried multiple combinations of `virtual` inheritances to no avail.

In particular, I thought *virtualizing* both inheritances between red interfaces and both inheritances between green classes (i.e. all purple arrows) would be enough, but it does not solve the problem.

What would be the correct construct here?

**Edit**: this question is different from the mentionned one since it includes pure abstract classes, which relates to the specific error message referenced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit)

Comment: ConnectableTrack should be "virtual IConnectableTrack" already.

Comment: @Charles the question you mention only deals with member data. Here the issue arise with pure abstract classes.

Comment: @Silverspur I'm aware; however, there's still diamond inheritance of `ConnectableTrack` so I suggested it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Track` has four instances of `IConnectableTrack` and compiler doesn't know which one to use. Make top 3 arrows virtual.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y1e9LwDI0IVaERaW

```
class IConnectableTrack {};
class Object {};
class ConnectableTrack: public virtual IConnectableTrack, public Object {};
class IOccupiableTrack: public virtual IConnectableTrack {};
class OccupiableTrack: public IOccupiableTrack {};
class ISignalledTrack: public virtual IConnectableTrack {};
class SignalledTrack: public ISignalledTrack {};
class Track: public OccupiableTrack, public SignalledTrack {};

void f(IConnectableTrack&) {}

int main() {
    Track t;
    f(t);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I also tried that, but visibly did not clean correctly before compiling. This works.