# C++: override class inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

There are two classes in a library I use, lets call them `class A` and `class B` to keep things generic. `Class B` inherits from `class A`, so something like:

```
class A{
    ...
}

class B: public A{
    ...
}
```

So nothing fancy, but I can't edit either of these classes directly. Now I wanted to add some functionality to class A, so I subclass it as, say, `myClassA`, and add the functionality in the subclass. This works great when I use `myClassA`, but of course anywhere I use `classB` still inherits from the original `class A`, and not `myClassA`.

How can I make a subclass of `class B` that inherits from `myClassA` instead of the original `classA`? Would it work to simply have the subclass inherit from BOTH `class B` and `myClassA`, even though `class B` already inherits from the original `class A`?

EDIT: I just tried the "Inherit from BOTH" option and can confirm it does *not* work, at least not without a lot more work. Probably the diamond issue mentioned in the comments. So unless there is a way to *override* `class B`'s inheritance of `class A` with `myClassA`, I may have to simply re-implement the changes I made to my subclass of `class A` in a subclass of `class B`, although that would be a violation of the DRY principle...

EDIT 2: To make this a little more concrete, take for example the standard "shape" class example. So in this case you'll have a base class of, say, `rectangle`, and `rectangle` is in tern inherited by a class of `square`. Now I want to add functionality, say a "move" function that shifts the position of the object by a specified amount. This would be the same for both `rectangle` and `square`, so ideally I'd implement it in the `rectangle` class, and `square` would inherit it. However, since I don't have access to the `rectangle` or `square` classes directly, I can only work with subclasses. Thus my desire to make a `square` subclass that inherits from *my* `rectangle` subclass rather than the base `rectangle` class.

EDIT 3: To restate and clarify the question in terms of the more concrete example, "Can I/How can I create a subclass of `square` but have it inherit from `my_rectange` (a `rectangle` subclass) INSTEAD OF inheriting from `rectangle`?" Or, to put it another way, "Can I/How can I replace a base class with something of my own if I can't modify the class directly?"

Comment: It sounds like you may be brushing up against [the diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit)

Comment: @scohe001 possible. I'll have to look into it more to see if that will be an issue. I guess worst case I simply subclass `class B` as well, and re-implement the stuff I added in the subclass of class A. The question though was if there was a way to "override" the inheritance - say replace *your* class A ancestor with *my* class A, which would avoid any such issue.

Comment: Umm... could you just extend Class B instead of Class A?

Comment: XY problem? Why do you want to add functionality to the classes you are not supposed to (I imagine, they are in a library)?

Comment: @3Dave A reasonable suggestion, except there are places where I use class A (or my subclass thereof) directly. Class B changes the behavior of Class A in ways that are sometimes, but not always, desirable.

Comment: @SergeyA Because the base classes (which, yes, are in a library) don't work *quite* the way I want, specifically in this case in regards to file locks.

Comment: Might be obvious, but in your override you can specify which version of an overridden method you want to call. `classA::foo()`, etc.

Comment: You can't modify `A` nor `B`. Then use a new class `C` that DOESN'T inherits from A,B, but contains as a member an instance of `B`. The required additions may work with this object (use its methods).

Comment: Sounds like you need composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @Ripi2 It's looking like your suggestion might be the best option here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T /* T must be derived from A */> class myclsssA:T { /* ... */ }

new myclassA<B>()
```

This works sometimes depending on what you are doing. There's an extreme exactness to what this can do or not do, and there just aren't enough details in the question to even get close to knowing.

This makes myclassA the most-derived form so it can override all virtual methods successfully. But if you don't make the instances of B, it won't help at all.

Comment: See my edit2 for a more concrete example. Would this work in that case? If so, how?

Comment: @ibrewster: Notice how this only does anything if you are in control of creating B (or in this case square).

Comment: Yes, I have full control of the instantiation of the classes, it's only the definitions that I don't have control over

Comment: `template <class T:A>` doesn't compile... Did you mean `=`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: After two more failures at finding the syntax, I took the type filter out.