# How to fix this ambiguity for diamond problem

Tags: c++

I am exploring diamond problem. I have written below code. However it shows ambiguous issue. How to resolve it?
Is it possible without overriding method in Snake class?

```
    #include <iostream>
    class LivingThing {
    protected:
       void breathe()
       {
          std::cout << "I'm breathing as a living thing." << std::endl;
       }
    };

    class Animal : virtual protected LivingThing {
    protected:
       void breathe() {
          std::cout << "I'm breathing as a Animal." << std::endl;
       }
    };

    class Reptile : virtual public LivingThing {
    public:
       void breathe() {
          std::cout << "I'm breathing as a Reptile." << std::endl;
       }
    };

    class Snake : public Animal, public Reptile {

    };

    int main() {
       Snake snake;
       snake.breathe();
       getchar();
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: i'd rather fix the hierachy, in what world an `Reptile` is not an `Animal`? Why do you have multiple inheritance in the first place?

Comment: Please provide the actual error message. Also, why do you use protected inheritance in `Animal`?

Comment: Have you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that `Animal` and `Reptile` both overwrite the `LivingThing::breathe()` method with their own version. `Snake`, thus, inherits two different methods, both called `breathe`, one from each of its base classes. When you then write

```
snake.breathe();
```

the name `breathe` is ambiguous because it could refer to either `Animal::breathe` or `Reptile::breathe`. You have to explicitly tell which one should be called, for example

```
snake.Reptile::breathe();
```

This is most likely not what you wanted. `breathe()` is not a virtual method. You most likely wanted it to be a virtual method, however, in which case you most definitely should have a look at [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit).