# Is this example working with virtual inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, overriding, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, virtual-inheritance

Could I do this?

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void aFoo() = 0;
};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
  virtual void aFoo() { ... }
};

class D : public A {};

class C : public B, virtual public D {};
```

The issue is with the implementation of `aFoo()` in `B` and the lack of it in `C`. When it comes to compiling I see this error:

`error: no unique final overrider for ‘virtual void A::aFoo()’ in ‘C’`

Shouldn't it be possible to override a pure virtual method of a virtual base class in `B`?

---

Just edited the example to match the actual use case. Now looking at it in this simplified way I am not quite sure if this is even possible, let alone good design.

Comment: You shouldn't inherit from A and B if B already inherits from A. Thats wrong. And as the error message says, you have to override Foo from A, because you inherit directly from it. (assuming the top class, where code is missing, is class A)

Comment: I see, I made a mistake in the example. C is supposed to implement another type, D, which is again inheriting A virtually. I will fix that, I'm very sorry for the confusion here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit)

Comment: Which compiler gives you that error? It's fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ac9c6297841d5b4)

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the link. My question is more about the usage of pure virtual functions within the diamond problem. I'm afraid the answers there do not quite lead to any information about this.

Comment: Caleth, this is GCC 9.3.0. I believe you test is compiling because you did not try to instantiate C.

Comment: RoQuOTriX Thank you for your comment, but shouldn't the virtual method inherited from B be already sufficient? At least that's what I thought would happen when using virtual base classes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need virtual inheritance in this way:

```
struct A {
    virtual int f() = 0;
};
struct B : virtual A {
    int f() { return 1; }
};
struct C : virtual A {};
struct D : B, C {};

int main() {
    D d;
    return d.f();
}
```

In the dupe I commented you can see this relation

```
  A  
 / \  
B   C  
 \ /  
  D
```

for virtual inheritance and

```
A   A  
|   |
B   C  
 \ /  
  D
```

without virtual inheritance.

In the second case `D` contains two function definitions. One is implemented and one isn't.

Comment: This is the perfect answer to my question (also one that luckily solves the problem).

Thank you so much! :)