# Unexpected size for class that inherits twice from same class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Here the data member of the base class is private. Please explain this code. why the output of this program is `80`.

```
  #include<iostream> 
  using namespace std; 

  class base { 
      int arr[10]; 
   }; 
      
  class b1: public base { }; 
      
  class b2: public base { }; 
      
  class derived: public b1, public b2 {}; 
      
  int main(void) 
  { 
    cout << sizeof(derived); 
    return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: This is the diamond problem, see [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit)

Comment: Are you expecting a private member to occupy less space than other members?

Comment: @Botje There is no diamond here. `derived` just has two subobjects of `base` type

Comment: what output did you expect? Why do you think `80` would be a problem?

Comment: @user7860670 The inheritance diagram looks like a diamond and OP has the exact problem listed in [the C++ faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond)

Comment: Please formulate your question better; now people are guessing and make fun of it. 'Botje' already explained why the size is 80 and not 40 if that's what you had expected.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what private modifier does. In your code snippet it simply prevents non-members and non-friends of A from accessing it. It's just an access-control modifier.
Instances of child class will have data members of its parent, even though child class won't have (direct) access to it.

> NOTE : if private, child class cannot peek in parent even though it contains it.