# Inheritance mess with pure virtual functions, any way to not have to re-define them all?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

So I found myself in a bit of a mess of a class hierarchy.

I have code that looks a bit like that, oversimplified:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Parent {
  virtual void pureVirtual() = 0;
};

struct Child : public Parent {
  void pureVirtual() override {
    std::cout << "Child::pureVirtual()" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Brother: public Parent {
};

struct GrandChild : public Child, public Brother {
};

GrandChild test;
```

The compilation fails with:

> object of abstract class type "GrandChild" is not allowed: -- pure virtual function
> "Parent::pureVirtual" has no overriderC/C++(322)

I don't fully understand why the implementation of `pureVirtual` is not inherited by `GrandChild` from `Child`.

In practice, I have tons of pure-virtual functions to "re-implement", that is, just writing lines like:

```
struct GrandChild : public Child, public Brother {
  void pureVirtual() override {
    Child::pureVirtual();
  }
};
```

I would have expected the compilator to automatically use the implementation from `Child`.

Is there any sort of trick I can use to tell the compiler that I am gonna re-use all the implementations from `Child`?

Anyway I probably have to think of a better design, but this got me interested if there are easy solutions.

Comment: Child and Brother have _separate_ Parent instances.  You probably mean to use `virtual` base class for `Parent` based on your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you actually *are* getting two `pureVirtual` functions. C++ isn't smart enough to merge the two by default. You can use [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) to force the behavior.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Parent {
  virtual void pureVirtual() = 0;
};

struct Child : virtual public Parent {
  void pureVirtual() override {
    std::cout << "Child::pureVirtual()" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Brother : virtual public Parent {};

struct GrandChild : public Child, public Brother {};

int main() {
  GrandChild test;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the keyword I was looking for. I ended up kind-of emulating virtual inheritance, with GrandChild actually storing an instance of Brother instead of inheriting from it, and forwarding calls to the pure virtual methods to the internal Brother instance.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't fully understand why the implementation of `pureVirtual` is not inherited by `GrandChild` from `Child`.

Actually, `GrandChild` does inherit the `override` implementation of `pureVirtual()` in `Child`.

But, `GrandChild` also inherits `pureVirtual()` from `Brother`.  `Brother` is abstract since it does not `override` its version of `pureVirtual()`, hence `GrandChild` is also abstract unless it provides an `override` for `Brother::pureVirtual()` as well.

You have a classic Diamond hierarchy.  You need to use **virtual inheritance** to solve it.

[How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/)

[Solving the Diamond Problem with Virtual Inheritance](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)