# C++: Ambiguos function call even with unique function names at each inheritence level

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous

Code -

```
#include<iostream>
              
    using namespace std;
         
class P {
    public:
    void print()  { cout <<" Inside P"; }
    };
          
class Q : public P {
    public:
    void print() { cout <<" Inside Q"; }
    };
         
class Q2: public P {
    public:
    void print2() { cout <<" Inside Q2"; }
    };
          
class R: public Q2, public Q { };
          
int main(void)
{
    R r; 
    r.print(); // error: request for member ‘print’ is ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

**Expected behavior:** No ambiguous call on 3rd line in main.

**Actual behavior:** Ambiguous call on 3rd line in main

**Rationale:** I expected class Q to hide the print() function of class P. I would expect an ambiguous call error when Q2 has the same function name as R or Q (or even P?). But I deliberately changed the function name in Q2 to 'print2' to avoid this error. This error goes away when I remove 'Q2' as parent class of R. Is this happening because 'Q2' inherits 'print' from 'P'?

**Note:** I know similar questions have been asked on data hiding for regular inheritance and ambiguous calls in case of inheritance from multiple classes, but this case is sort of a mixture of two, and I did not find any specific answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit)

Comment: @StephenNewell it does help me understand why this is happening, but my comment to Sam Varshavchik's answer below further confuses me. I thought that print was being inherited form P through Q2, but when I changed the access modified of print in P to private, I still get the same error (AFAIK, private components of a parent class should not be inherited?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected class Q to hide the print() function of class P

This has nothing to do with `Q` hiding the superclass's `print()`.

`Q2` inherits from `P`, and therefore inherits `print()`.

```
class R: public Q2, public Q { };
```

`print()` is inherited from both Q2 and from Q. Whether they turn out to be the same or different methods is immaterial. The point is that it is ambigous which `print()` method `R.print()` resolves to.

> would expect an ambiguous call error when Q2 has the same function name

But it does. It inherits it.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting as well, but even if I change the access modifier of print in P to private, it still happens? (g++-7 7.4.0)

Comment: Whether a method is private or public does not affect inheritance, it only determines whether or not, if there is no ambiguous inheritance, the inherited function is accessible or not.

Comment: Wow, that's news to me! Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Not only does public/private not affect inheritance, it doesn't even affect lookup or overload resolution!

Answer (score 1):

This is very typical C++ [Diamond problem](https://coderslegacy.com/c/diamond-problem-cpp/) with multiple inheritance.

what you have is when R call the print functions he does not know from which print to cal.

you can solve this by helping the R class object to specify which print you want to call.

below modification can illustrate this.

```
#include<iostream>
              
    using namespace std;
         
class P {
    public:
    void print()  { cout <<" Inside P\n"; }
    };
          
class Q : public P {
    public:
    void print() { cout <<" Inside Q\n"; }
    };
         
class Q2: public P {
    public:
    void print2() { cout <<" Inside Q2\n"; }
    };
          
class R: public Q2, public Q { };
          
int main(void)
{
    R r; 
    r.Q::print(); 
    r.Q2::print();
    // r.P::print();  ambiguous base call.
    // r.print();     ambiguous member
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew about using the scope resolution operator as a workaround, but didn't realize the effect of the implicit inheritance of member functions from P to Q2.