# object constructed as one base class, method calculated as other base class (diamond inheritance and code redundancy)

Tags: c++, code-duplication, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem, constructor-overloading

I have a diamond inheritance scheme in C++ solved through virtual inheritance.

The base class is `general` has two attributes and some method using them.

```
class general {
    double attr1, attr2;
public:
    general(double attr1, double attr2) {
        this->attr1=attr1;
        this->attr2=attr2;
    }
    virtual double somemethod() {
        return attr1*attr2;
    }
};
```

A `specialrestriction` is a `general` with a special restriction that both attributes are equal.

```
class specialrestriction : public general {
public:
    specialrestriction(double attr) : general(attr, attr) {};
};
```

A `specialrule` slightly modifieds `somemethod()` with a special rule.

```
class specialrule : public general {
public:
    specialrule(double a, double b) : general(2*a, 2*b) {}
    double somemethod() override {
        return general::somemethod()*0.785398;
    }
};
```

Finally a `restrictionandrule` is a `general` with the same restriction as a `specialrestriction` (I would like to use its constructor), and the same special rule for computing the `somemethod()` as a `specialrule` (I would like to use its `somemethod()` method). The solution I have so far is:

```
class restrictionandrule : public virtual specialrule, public virtual specialrestriction {
public:
    restrictionandrule(double attr) : specialrestriction(attr), specialrule(attr,attr) {} //the call to the constructor of specialrule is (almost?) redundant
    double somemethod() override { return specialrule::somemethod(); } //only specialrule overrides somemethod(), is there another way to 
};

int main() {
    restrictionandrule c(5);
    std::cout<<"restrictionandrule::somemethod is " << c.somemethod()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As put in the code's comments, I think the code of `restrictionandrule` is redundant. My intention when doing this was avoiding as much code redundancy as possible, but couldn't go any further.

*(As a side comment, I'd like the language to solve the `somemethod()` ambiguity with less code (e.g., by calling the first parent's method by default), but to my knowledge that's just the standard, and this is not my question.)*

My question is this: Since both `specialrule` and `specialrestriction` do little more (from the programmer's POV, I know I'm oversimplifying!) than calling the base constructor, I don't really need both of them, but C++ enforces calling both. **Is there a better way to do this? Do I have this problem because I'm misunderstanding the `an A is a B' relationship?** (perhaps because derived classes are not supposed to have *less* attributes than the base?)

Comment: Personally I would make `circle` a specialisation of `ellipse` only.
.
Also I think `shape` should be abstract, and you should also have a `rectangle` class that `square` specialises.
.
Your hierarchy would then make more sense.

Comment: Also don't forget to add virtual destructors to all of the classes.
.
And don't pull in any unnecessary includes in header files (e.g. `iostream`)

Comment: Another aspect to consider is to use containment whenever possible, instead of inheritance

Comment: Why is a circle a square??? Part of the definition of a square is having four straight sides; a circle does not. If you make your inheritance diagram match what you are representing, you might have fewer issues.

Comment: *"I have a diamond inheritance scheme"* -- no, you do not. Your `circle` class has two distinct `shape` base classes, one the base of `ellipse` and one the base of `square`. This is not a diamond but a 'V'. A diamond would make `shape` a virtual base class (not `ellipse` and `square`) so that there is only one `shape` per `circle`. See [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/)

Comment: Maybe with `square` you are thinking of a mixin or concept. It's a shape where x and y dimensions are equal. As suggested you should have a rectangle and the `shape::area` method belongs in `rectangle`. Think about triangles, trapezes, 5 pointed stars, ... any other shape. None of them have an area of `base*height`. There is no good base formula for area so `shape::area` should be purely virtual. The square, circle, 5 pointed star would have the mixin/concept of equal width and height.

Comment: Following the edit, I would contain `specialrule` and `specialrestriction` as members of `restrictionandrule`, given they are probably orthogonal.

"Choose containment over inheritance" most likely prevents you having to deal with a diamond inheritance issue in 99% of cases.

Comment: @Rafael I would recommend you read up on SOLID principles if you haven't done so already.  e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

Comment: @Den-Jason That is a good (partial) answer I'm willing to accept. But I'm misunderstanding the 'an A is a B' relationship, or is it just too-specific a case that happens to be better to solve by containment rather than inheritance in C++ do to its syntax?

Comment: @Den-Jason, thanks, I'll give it a look. I only had one formal OOP course in my undergraduate studies (quite a few years ago), and I certainly may be missing some concepts.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I find it useful to think of "use inheritance ONLY when I need to specialise behaviour" and use containment for all other cases.  The SOLID principles will reinforce this in your mind.

Comment: @Rafael I also recommend the book "Design Patterns Explained" by Shalloway and Trott, which uses the concept of "Commonality and Variability analysis" throughout.  That provided me a big improvement in how I architected systems - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-Patterns-Explained-Perspective-Object-Oriented/dp/0321247140

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would implement the hierarchy

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES         //for older compilers
#include <cmath>

class shape {
public:
    virtual ~shape() {}
    virtual double area() = 0;
};

class rectangle : public shape {
protected:
    double mBase;
    double mHeight;

public:
    rectangle(double base, double height) : mBase(base), mHeight(height) {}
    virtual ~rectangle() {}
    virtual double area() override { return mBase*mHeight; }
};

class square : public rectangle {
public:
    square(double side) : rectangle(side, side) {};
    virtual ~square() {}
};


class ellipse : public shape {
protected:
    double mMajor;
    double mMinor;

public:
    ellipse(double major, double minor) : mMajor(major), mMinor(minor) {}
    ~ellipse() {}
    virtual double area() override { return mMajor * mMinor * M_PI; }
};

class circle : public ellipse {
public:
    circle(double radius) : ellipse(radius,radius) {}
    virtual ~circle() {}
};

// --------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {            
    std::unique_ptr<shape> widget = std::make_unique<circle>(2.0);
    std::cout << "Area is: " << widget->area() << "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/4bTscEEvT

Next step would be to template the types.

You *could* use a std::pair instead of having mBase, mHeight etc, but then you would be sacrificing readability for a dubious level of avoiding duplication.

Comment: Uh, sorry for the edits, I appreciate your answer. I was just a bit bugged that the problem was not in the underlying ontology, but in the application of multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you aren't actually using `specialrestriction` doesn't mean you can just leave it uninitialized.  For every object of a class type, its constructor will be called upon construction (and its destructor upon destruction).  In general the compiler can't know that the body of `specialrestriction`'s constructor is empty (for instance, if it was defined in a different compilation unit), so failing to call it could easily violate `specialrestriction`'s assumptions about its internal state.

---

Note that you haven't correctly implemented virtual inheritance.  Your hierarchy still has two instances of `general`.  An object of type `restrictionandrule` looks like this:

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│restrictionandrule       │
│ ┌─────────────────────┐ │
│ │specialrule          │ │
│ │ ┌─────────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │general          │ │ │
│ │ │                 │ │ │
│ │ │                 │ │ │
│ │ │                 │ │ │
│ │ └─────────────────┘ │ │
│ └─────────────────────┘ │
│                         │
│ ┌─────────────────────┐ │
│ │specialrestriction   │ │
│ │ ┌─────────────────┐ │ │
│ │ │general          │ │ │
│ │ │                 │ │ │
│ │ │                 │ │ │
│ │ │                 │ │ │
│ │ └─────────────────┘ │ │
│ └─────────────────────┘ │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

Each of the `specialrule` and `specialrestriction` syb-objects has its own `general` sub-object, and so you need a separate constructor call to initialize each of them separately.  In fact, in your specific example your two `general` sub-objects have *different values* for `attr1` and `attr2`.  This is also why you need to explicitly override `somemethod` in `restrictionandrule`.  Without your help the compiler doesn't know which direct parent you want to call it on.

To eliminate the extra `general` sub-object, `specialrule` and `specialrestriction` need to inherit virtually from `general` (`restrictionandrule` does not need to inherit virtually from `specialrule` and `specialrestriction` though).