# Ambiguous base error with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, radix

Hi I'm making a computational graph library. I have an issue with my inheritance classes.
I represent operations and input/output as nodes, there are two types of nodes - nodes that can have inputs and nodes that can have outputs. The inputs and outputs are vectors containing ptrs to other nodes. The forward node class is for nodes that have output connections and backward node class if for nodes with input connections only. The Output node class's add input function is overwritten to only allow one input. There is an add node, which takes inputs and sums them. Sorry for the long block of code but I think it's all relevant for the issue here:

```
/*
Computational Graph library
*/

#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

/*
***************************************************************************************************************************
NODE
- contains value
*/

template <class T>
class Node
{
protected:
    T m_value;
public:
    virtual T value() const;
};

template <class T> 
T Node<T>::value() const
{
    return this->m_value;
}

/*
***************************************************************************************************************************
BACKWARD NODE
- contains inputs
*/

template <class T>
class BackwardNode : public Node<T>
{
protected:
    int m_numInputs;
    std::vector<Node<T>*> m_inputs;
public:
    virtual int findInput(const Node<T>* n) const;
    virtual void addInput(Node<T>* n);
    virtual void removeInput(Node<T>* n);
};

/* find  input index by node ptr, returns -1 if not found */
template <class T>
int BackwardNode<T>::findInput(const Node<T>* n) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->m_numInputs; ++i)
    {
        if (this->m_inputs[i] == n)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/* add input by node ptr */
template <class T>
void BackwardNode<T>::addInput(Node<T>* n)
{
    assert(this->findInput(n) == -1); // make sure output isn't already present
    this->m_inputs.push_back(n);
    this->m_numInputs++;
}

/* remove input by node ptr */
template <class T>
void BackwardNode<T>::removeInput(Node<T>* n)
{
    int index = this->findInput(n);
    assert(index != -1); // make sure input is present
    this->m_inputs.erase(this->m_inputs.begin() + index);
    this->m_numInputs--;
}

/*
***************************************************************************************************************************
FORWARD NODE
- contains outputs
*/

template <class T>
class ForwardNode : public Node<T>
{
protected:
    int m_numOutputs;
    std::vector<Node<T>*> m_outputs;
public:
    virtual int findOutput(const Node<T>* n) const;
    virtual void addOutput(Node<T>* n);
    virtual void removeOutput(Node<T>* n);
};

/* find output index by node ptr, returns -1 if not found */
template <class T>
int ForwardNode<T>::findOutput(const Node<T>* n) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->m_numOutputs; ++i)
    {
        if (this->m_outputs[i] == n)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/* add output by node ptr */
template <class T>
void ForwardNode<T>::addOutput(Node<T>* n)
{
    assert(this->findOutput(n) == -1); // make sure output isn't already present
    this->m_outputs.push_back(n);
    this->m_numOutputs++;
}

/* remove output by node ptr */
template <class T>
void ForwardNode<T>::removeOutput(Node<T>* n)
{
    int index = this->findOutput(n);
    assert(index != -1); // make sure input is present
    this->m_outputs.erase(this->m_outputs.begin() + index);
    this->m_numOutputs--;
}

/*
***************************************************************************************************************************
INPUT
- exec writes to value from argument
- no inputs allowed
- multiply outputs allowed
*/ 

template <class T>
class Input : public ForwardNode<T>
{
private:
public:
    Input();
    void exec(const T& value);
};

/* ctor */
template <class T>
Input<T>::Input()
{
    this->m_numOutputs = 0;
    this->m_outputs = {};
    this->m_value = 0.0;
}

/* execute */
template <class T>
void Input<T>::exec(const T& value)
{
    this->m_value = value;
}

/*
***************************************************************************************************************************
OUTPUT
- exec writes to value from single input value
- only one input allowed
- no outputs allowed
*/ 

template <class T>
class Output : public BackwardNode<T>
{
private:
public:
    Output();
    void addInput(Node<T>* n); // override add input to only allow 1 input
    void exec();
};

/* ctor */
template <class T>
Output<T>::Output()
{
    this->m_numInputs = 0;
    this->m_inputs = {};
    this->m_value = 0.0;
}

/* execute */
template <class T>
void Output<T>::exec()
{
    this->m_value = this->m_inputs[0]->value();
}

/* add input override (only 1 input allowed) */
template <class T>
void Output<T>::addInput(Node<T>* n)
{
    assert(this->findInput(n) == -1); // make sure output isn't already present
    assert(this->m_numInputs == 0); // only one input is allowed
    
    this->m_inputs.push_back(n);
    this->m_numInputs++;
}

/*
***************************************************************************************************************************
ADD
- exec sums input values into value
- no limit on inputs/outputs
*/ 

template <class T>
class Add : public BackwardNode<T>, ForwardNode<T>
{
private:
public:
    Add();
    void exec();
};

/* ctor */
template <class T>
Add<T>::Add()
{
    this->m_numInputs = 0;
    this->m_numOutputs = 0;
    this->m_inputs = {};
    this->m_outputs = {};
    this->m_value = 0.0;
}

/* execute */
template <class T>
void Add<T>::exec()
{
    this->m_value = 0.0; // set to identity
    for (int i = 0; i < this->m_numInputs; ++i)
    {
        this->m_value += this->m_inputs[i]->value();
    }
}
```

The arguments for adding inputs/outputs are of the Node class form (as general as possible). However, I get errors on compilation when I try and add inputs/outputs to the add node object.

```
error: ‘Node<double>’ is an ambiguous base of ‘Add<double>’
   20 |     input1.addOutput(&add1);
error: ‘ForwardNode<double>’ is not an accessible base of ‘Add<double>’
   25 |     add1.addOutput(&output1);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Maybe this is to do with the Node being passed as an argument when it should be something more specific. Hopefully if you're reading you'll understand what this error means?

Comment: `class Add : public BackwardNode<T>, ForwardNode<T>` should be `class Add : public BackwardNode<T>, public ForwardNode<T>`. Additionally, you have run into the [dreaded diamond problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit) which is solved by using *`virtual` inheritance*.

Comment: Oh I see, that was stupid of me. A very dreaded diamond problem indeed. Do you add virtual inheritance by adding virtual to functions?

Comment: No, you place it when you specify what derives from what. The linked quesion should explain the syntax. Formally, *`virtual` inheritance* has nothing to do with `virtual` functions.