# solve field ambiguity in multiple inheritance C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I was checking out inheritance and got a field ambiguity compile-time error.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int a;
};

class Derived1: Base {};

class Derived2: Base {};

class DerivedDerived: Derived1, Derived2 {
public:
    void show()  {   std::cout << a;  }
};

int main(void)
{
    DerivedDerived d;
    d.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there some way of telling the compiler to only use one instance of `a`? or rather, telling it "send `a` only to Derived1, or make Derived1's `a` more prominent in the multiple inheritance" (taking in account that there might other fields to be inherited).

Similarly to how in Python the first inherited function called in multiple inheritance is of the first inherited class.

I have tried to put `a` as virtual, and even tried to use virtual inheritance but none of these seem to have the desired effect.

Just to be clear, I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve the resolution scope operator, but instead ingrained in the inheritance protocol.

Is there anything like it?

Comment: Derived1 and Derived2 have **private** inheritance of Base.  DerivedDerived can't access either Derived1::Base::a or Derived2::Base::a.  **But** if it wasn't private, then either `a` could be accessed by qualifying the name with which one you wanted to access, `void show() { Derived1* d = this; std::cout << d->a;  }`

Comment: @Manuel You can write for example class Derived1: virtual public Base {};

class Derived2: virtual public Base {};

Comment: "and even tried to use virtual inheritance but none of these seem to have the desired effect." why not? Virtual inheritance should have exactly the desired effect, that `DerivedDerived` has only 1 `a` member

Comment: "I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve the resolution scope operator" why?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659142/2041317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to make any variation of your example work, you need public inheritance here:

```
class Derived1: public Base {};

class Derived2: public Base {};
```

Next, you need to decide: how many instances of `a` you want to have in `class DerivedDerived` - one or two?

If you want only one `a`, then virtual inheritance solves it:

```
class Derived1: virtual public Base {};

class Derived2: virtual public Base {};
```

If you want to have a separate `a` in each of `Derived1` and `Derived2`, but want to always use `Derived1::a` in `DerivedDerived`, then it can be done with a single `using` declaration:

```
class DerivedDerived: Derived1, Derived2 {
public:
    using Derived1::a;
    void show()  {   std::cout << a;  }
};
```

Comment: Good answer, pointing out the **design decision** at the root of the decision rather than blindly recommending virtual inheritance. +1.