# C++ Initialize unordered_map by method called by Constructor initializer list throws exception

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm trying to populate an unordered_map [class member] in a method called in the Constructor initializer list.  I get a runtime exception at `map[0] = 1` which seems to be due to the member not being constructed prior to the method being called.  (I put a breakpoint on the unordered_map constructor and it was not hit).  Is there a way to force the construction of the unordered_map member prior to the method being called?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Base
{
public:
   Base(int chan) { }
};
class Foo : public Base
{
   std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
   int Init(int chan)
   {
      // fill map
      map[0] = 1;
      map[1] = 3;
      return map[chan];
   }
public:
   Foo(int chan) : Base(Init(chan)) { }
};

int main()
{
   Foo foo(0);
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: `Foo` contains `map`.  `Foo` derives from `Base`. Base classes are initialized before the derived class, so you are right. `map` does not exist yet.

Comment: The way you have presented the problem `map` could be `static`, and [this allows you significant leeway](https://godbolt.org/z/xf35e6b1z). Not sure if this accurately represents the problem you are trying to solve, though.

Comment: Yes this does in fact.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top, here are two ideas I have. First:

```
struct MapWrapper {
  std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
};

class Foo : private MapWrapper, public Base {
  /* The rest of the class can remain unchanged, except that
     there's no `map` member; it's inherited from MapWrapper */
};
```

This forces `map` to be constructed before `Base`.

---

Second:

```
class Foo : public Base
{
   std::unordered_map<int, int> map;

   static std::unordered_map<int, int> MakeMap() {
     std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
     map[0] = 1;
     map[1] = 3;
     return map;
   }
   Foo(int chan, std::unordered_map<int, int>&& temp_map)
     : Base(temp_map[chan]), map(std::move(temp_map)) {}
public:
   Foo(int chan) : Foo(chan, MakeMap()) {}
};
```

This uses delegating constructor trick to essentially simulate a local variable in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: While a static member was what I needed to do, I soon needed another member variable of std::vector to populate in the same area.  Well, I didn't get any errors calling `push_back`, the elements were successfully added, but later when I accessed the member, the elements were gone!  I assume this is due to the std::vector constructor removing them.

Comment: I inadvertently had virtual inheritance for the Base class...
`class Foo : private MapWrapper, public virtual Base`
The method was executed before the MapWrapper constructor.
I had to add `virtual` to both to get the MapWrapper constructor to execute first (or remove the `virtual` altogether).  Not real sure of what effect that keyword has (other than the behavior I saw!)

Comment: [On virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit)