# When should constructor of virtual base class be called?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, virtual-inheritance

Consider the following example:

```cpp
struct Grandpa {
    Grandpa(int x) {}
};

struct Dad : Grandpa {
    Dad(int y) : Grandpa(15) {}
};

struct Son : Dad {
    Son(int z) : Dad(z) {}
};

int main () {
    Son s(10);
}
```

It compiles just fine, however, if I make `Grandpa` not just baseclass of `Dad`, but virtual baseclass:

```cpp
struct Grandpa {
    Grandpa(int x) {}
};

struct Dad : virtual Grandpa {
    Dad(int y) : Grandpa(15) {}
};

struct Son : Dad {
    Son(int z) : Dad(z) {}
};

int main () {
    Son s(10);
}
```

This code doesn't compile! Compilation fails with

```
example.cpp: In constructor ‘Son::Son(int)’:
example.cpp:12:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Grandpa::Grandpa()’
   12 |         Son(int z) : Dad(z) {}
```

What are the rules, according to C++ standard, regarding virtual baseclasses' constructor calls?

Comment: The constructor of a virtual base class is called from the constructor of the **most derived** class, in this case, from the constructor of `Son`. Since there is no default constructor for`Grandpa`, the constructor for `Son` needs to explicitly call the `Grandpa` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856627/when-should-constructor-of-virtual-base-class-be-called?noredirect=1#comment137256198_77856627) in comments, and [Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856696/9774145) in answers have pointed out:

> The constructor of a virtual base class is called from the constructor of the most derived class, in this case, from the constructor of `Son`. Since there is no default constructor for `Grandpa`, the constructor for Son needs to explicitly call the `Grandpa` constructor.

The closest thing that corresponds to this answer in C++ standard I found is:
[15.6.2 Initializing bases and members # 13.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#13.1)

What it says, is that order of which constructor is called is *first* virtual baseclasses (even non-direct baseclasses!!), and then direct non-virtual baseclassses. So compiler, after not seeing call to `Grandpa` constructor in `Son` constructor, doesn't bother calling `Dad` constructor to find call to `Grandpa` constructor there: compiler decides to fail compilation, which is OK for compiler, according to standard.

Comment: If you know when virtual inheritance is needed, it becomes obvious why construction has to work this way. That situation is "[diamond inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659142/212858)"

Comment: @Useless however, at first glance, in situation where no multiple inheritance is used, like in the example in question, compilation error seems wrong.

Comment: That's because virtual inheritance has no utility at all in this code. It's an artificial example that avoids the only situation where virtual inheritance is ever needed.

Comment: @Useless it's not artificial. If you have class that is virtual base for every other class (like `Object` in Java [from question: `Grandpa`]), and there is one class `Vector` [from question: `Son`] that doesn't use multiple inheritance and is derived from some class `Container` [from question: `Dad`] non-virtually, that is derived from `Object` virtually. We might need `Object` to be virtual base of `Vector`, because we might derive some classes from `Vector` and some other not derived from `Container` class (yet other class might be derived from `Object` virtually)

Comment: You either end up with a diamond inheritance graph or you don't. Virtual inheritance only becomes useful once you have that diamond inheritance graph. Your example doesn't have a diamond inheritance graph, so virtual inheritance isn't doing anything useful in it. Also, in general, copying Java-style OO in C++ is probably a mistake, or at least un-idiomatic.

Comment: "seems wrong" think through the alternative... Son's constructor needs to initialize Grandpa. For non-static data members, that would involve using the mem-initializer from that constructor or if not from the member declaration or if not default initialized. For direct bases, that involves using the mem-initializer or if not default initialized. For virtual bases, you are suggesting mem-initializer or if not search through all base class constructors (which isn't possible because they may be in other TUs) for how they initialize Grandpa, somehow rank those and use one.

Comment: It is impossible due to separate compilation but even if it weren't it's a lot of magical complexity for a fairly special case. Virtual inheritance is itself rare, using it without MI is rare indeed.

Comment: @JeffGarrett "which isn't possible because they may be in other TUs" -- thank you, now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create an instance of a class with a (direct or indirect) virtual base class, that top level constructor must call the constructor for the virtual base class.  Any constructor calls to the virtual base in intermediate classes will be ignored.

In your case, you are creating a `Son` and its constructor has no explicit call to `Grandpa`, so it gets an implicit call to `Grandpa()` (which causes the error you see).  The presence or absence of any call in `Dad`'s constructor is irrelevant; it will always be ignored.